# How to show a second MVC group as a dialog box in griffon

Tags: java, swing, grails, groovy, griffon

I can see how to instantiate a second MVC group, e.g.

```
def (loginPaneModel, loginPaneView, loginPaneController) =
      createMVCGroup('LoginPane', 'LoginPane', [:]);
view.loginPanel = loginPaneView.loginPanel
```

But I don't want to show as part of my main window.  I want it to pop up over it.  What do I call to do that?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the view panel as the root of a dialog in the parent MVC group. In the view for the group that yor code snippet is the controller of you could do something like this...

```
application(title:'your app', ....) {
  // your existing code...

  loginDialog = dialog(title:'Login Panel', visible:false) {
    panel(loginPanel)
  }
}
```

And then when you need to show the dialog (in the same controller)

```
view.loginDialog.visible = true
```

Nesting a dialog inside of another window has the side effect of setting the dialog's owner to the frame or dialog of the parent.  Having a dialog owned by another dialog/window is what causes the dialog to be linked with the parent and always float on top of that parent.  It will also raise/lower with the parent as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that only the first line is needed.  That was enough to pop up a window.  I believe the key, though, was to make the view a frame.

```
def frame = frame(title:'Login', pack:true, locationByPlatform:true) {
     ...
}
frame.pack()
frame.show()
```